# 2016 Toyota Camry Automatic Alarm Lock

Tags: locks, alarm

If you do not lock the 2016 Toyota Camry with the key, it does not turn on the alarm system.

1. Why does it not turn on automatically?
2. Can I set it up so it will turn on automatically?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't have a key fob remote to lock/unlock the doors?

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify your question, right now it reads to me like an opinion based question - roughly "why did Toyota engineers decide not to implement an automatic lock system on the 2016 Camry?" Only the engineers will know that for sure, the rest of us will be guessing. On the other hand if you're wondering about how it works, that is likely a question we could answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the owner's manual I found online, once all doors and trunk are closed, then locked, the alarm automatically activates after 30 seconds.

There may not be an external indication of this, other than the indicator on your central console which will go from "solid on" to "flashing," once the system is set.